# Missing Public Folder - Can't find it anywhere

Tags: exchange-2013, public-folders

A mail-enabled public folder has disappeared overnight (and is still within the deletion retention period) and the 2 users who have access to it swear they haven't deleted it. They also checked everywhere in their Outlook folders to spot if it was accidentally moved.

Assuming it's been deleted anyway (what else?), I followed the 2 recovery options in [this post](http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2013/08/23/recovering-public-folder-information-in-exchange-2013.aspx) without success:

- In Outlook 2010 (don't have 2013), I can't see the folder in the deleted items recovery
  wizard, although I have root access to the folder
- The `Get-PublicFolder –Identity “\NON_IPM_SUBTREE” –Recurse | FL

  > C:\pf2.txt` result list doesn't show the missing folder

Since that folder was receiving our company's contact@domain.com email, I tried recreating it to at least keep on getting messages, but I got the following message:

```
error
domain.local/Microsoft Exchange System Objects/Contact 34753643
The proxy address "smtp:contact@domain.com" is already being used by the proxy addresses or LegacyExchangeDN of "domain.local/Microsoft Exchange System Objects/Contact". Please choose another proxy address.
```

Where is the folder hiding? What else can I do to recover it?

PS: I don;t know if it's relevant, but Exchange was migrated to 2013 last week with a few problems. That public folder though was working fine until yesterday, post migration. All the other public folders are ok.

Comment: What version of Exchange did you migrate from? Did the problems you mention have anything to do with not being able to uninstall the old Exchange environment due to replicas still existing? If so what did you do to actually get the old Exchange servers uninstalled?

Comment: Exchange 2007, which hasn't been uninstalled yet.

Comment: My line of questions was leading to the possibility that there were some replicas for that folder on your old Exchange environment and upon uninstalling it you ran into errors and forced it out. ADSI Edit can be very dangerous but despite that some admins use it to forcibly remove exchange objects instead of finding the cause of the issue. Still curious to know what errors you ran into during migration. I know the migration happened about a week before hand but could be related.

Comment: You might also try `Get-Recipient contact@domain.com` just to see what if anything it returns.